# In HBase, Which one is faster either Update the record or Delete & insert new record

Tags: hbase

In HBase i want to replace the value with new value. In this case, which operation is faster either **updating the value using PUT command** or **DELETE the record and insert once again**?

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the comment above Delete would create an additional call.

MORE IMPORTANTLY: keep in mind that Delete does NOT REALLY delete a record, but simply puts a deletion marker on it. The record still exists and only truly gets deleted once a Flush and Major Compaction is performed. It will simply be ignored by HBase for all relevant operations. If you are doing a lot of these, this should be a serious consideration, because a bunch of these deletion markers can significantly delay your row-level scans, and would also leave the unnecessary data footprint.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a notable difference in time performance, but with a PUT you will have the history of previous values, which does not happen if you use DELELE

Comment: This is almost correct - PUT is just one call to HBase, delete+insert are two, so PUT should be a little faster. Other than that your answer is correct.